# IAccessible: How Get value of url bar in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm working in a code that promise get value from url bar, but now appear one compilation error in some parameters of IAccessible get_accValue property. So, how fix?

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is the my code:

```
uses
  oleacc;

function ffdoc: THandle;
const
  A_szClassName: array[0..6] of PChar = ('MozillaUIWindowClass','MozillaWindowClass',
  'MozillaWindowClass','MozillaWindowClass','MozillaContentWindowClass',
  'MozillaWindowClass','MozillaWindowClass');
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  for i:= 0 to 6 do
    Result:= FindWindowEx(Result,THandle(nil),A_szClassName[i],nil);
end;

function ffurl:string;
var
  acc: IAccessible;
  pw: PWChar;
begin
  if AccessibleObjectFromWindow(ffdoc,OBJID_CLIENT,IID_IAccessible,Pointer(acc)) = 0 then
    Acc.get_accValue(CHILDID_SELF,pw);
  Result:= pw;
end;
```

Comment: Lack of error checking does not bode well. If the compiler gives an error message, please tell us what it is. A THandle is not an HWND. Pass 0 rather than THandle(0).

Comment: And we don't know what PWChar is.

Comment: @David Heffernan, Here is the returned erro => http://prntscr.com/4m8l35

Comment: No. Please include it as text in the question.

Comment: You need to read the compiler message and then look at the types of the args you pass, and the types of the function params. Second param should be out WideString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the declaration for `oleacc.IAccessible.get_accValue()`, it is apparent why you are getting the error:

```
function Get_accValue(varChild: OleVariant; out pszValue: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
```

You are trying to pass a `PWChar` where an `out WideString` is expected.  Delphi is very strict when it comes to `var` and `out` parameters.

You need to change your `pw` variable:

```
function ffurl:string;
var
  acc: IAccessible;
  pw: WideString;
begin
  if AccessibleObjectFromWindow(ffdoc, OBJID_CLIENT, IID_IAccessible, acc) = 0 then
    acc.get_accValue(CHILDID_SELF, pw);
  Result := pw;
end;
```

COM uses `BSTR` for its strings, which Delphi wraps with `WideString`.  So always use `WideString` when passing strings in/out of COM interfaces.

Comment: @Ramy Lebeau, now compiled correctly! but the function ffurl return empty :(, but thank you for help me!